# gps service goes to sleep after phone goes to sleep

Tags: php, android, gps

I have an android app which is made out of an activity , receiver and service .
Activity is launched only once after install to set the user name and password and it starts the service .Receiver calls the service after phone boots .What happens is that service goes to sleep some time after phone goes to sleep and I need it to work all the time . I have put the call to website in a thread .This is the service

```
public class MyService extends Service {
public int indikator=0;
public String mojsadrzaj=new String();
public String pib=new String();
public String username=new String();
public String password=new String();
public String url=new String();
public URL myURL;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();


Toast.makeText(this,"Service created ...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    final SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("TruckMe", MODE_PRIVATE, null);



    String idvozaca=new String();
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists vozac (id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, idvozaca VARCHAR(15));");
    Cursor d=db.rawQuery("select idvozaca from vozac", null);


    if(d.getCount() > 0)
    {
        d.moveToLast();
        idvozaca=d.getString(d.getColumnIndex("idvozaca"));
        mojsadrzaj=idvozaca;

    }







    final Time t=new Time();



     final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                if(indikator != 0)
                {   


                try {

                    URL myURL = new URL(url);

                    URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
                    myURLConnection.connect();


                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
    System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();

                } 
                catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
                    // new URL() failed
                    // ...
                } 
                catch (IOException e) {   
                    // openConnection() failed
                    // ...
                }





                }
                indikator=1;
                handler.postDelayed(this, 180000);

            }
        };






    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);





final   LocationManager m=(LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

String locationprovider =m.getBestProvider(criteria,true);


        LocationListener l=new LocationListener() {


                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {


                    String zauzetost=new String();
                     zauzetost="ZAUZET";

                    String format="MM/dd/yyyy";
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format,Locale.US);
                    String date= sdf.format(new Date());


                t.setToNow();   


                String longitude=new String();
                String latitude=new String();
                String speed=new String();

                if((int)arg0.getSpeed()==0)
                {
                    speed="0";
                }
                else
                {
                speed=""+(((int)arg0.getSpeed()*3600)/1000);
                }
                longitude=""+  arg0.getLongitude();
                latitude=""+ arg0.getLatitude();



                String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                mydate=mydate.replaceAll("\\s","");

                url="http://www.compensatemeonline.com/truckmeonline/TruckMeOnline/S.php?id="+mojsadrzaj+"&a="+longitude+"&b="+latitude+"&c="+speed+"&d="+mydate+"&e="+date+"&f="+zauzetost;    
            Log.e("Poruka", url);

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            };




             runnable.run();

            m.requestLocationUpdates(locationprovider, 180000, 0, l);


        }











@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {






   return START_STICKY;

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Service started onstart...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
final SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("TruckMe", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.execSQL("drop table vozac;");


}
```

}

Since I do not want my service to ever sleeps should I decrease the m.requestLocationUpdates(locationprovider, 180000, 0, l) to 60000 , put everything from calling the gps from oncreate to onstartcommant or what else should I do .

Comment: Keeping the GPS and CPU on continuously will result in horrible battery life. Why would this be good for the user?

Comment: Because it as an app that is to follow the user without his notice .If the phone goes to sleep , we will not not where he was all that time won't we .